# mat-form-field forces inner component bounds in Angular 15+

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular15, angular17

I recently updated my angular app from version 14 to 17, which caused major issues in the app's styling.

One of the issues I'm having is a mat-form-field that includes a custom component instead of an input field.

It used to look like that when clicking on "Select Tag":
[image: Working example]

But now it looks like that:
[image: Issue]

So it seems like the mat-form-field is limiting the view for everything within it, and not allowing the div to be rendered outside.

my HTML looks like this:

```
<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="always">
  <mat-label>Parent</mat-label>
  <inner-component></inner-component>
</mat-form-field>
```

Where `inner-component` contains a div that uses the following CSS to create the floating window:

```
#hoverDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;

  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 27rem;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px dotted darkgrey;
  max-height: 60vh;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;

  .custom-scroll-bar {
    max-height: 37vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  .custom-scroll-bar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
  }

  .custom-scroll-bar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  }
}
```

I've been searching for an answer for this issue for a while now, but found no mention of this behavior anywhere.
Any lead would be much appreciated.

Comment: please share a working stackblitz with the issue replicated for debugging!

Comment: I'm not really able to do that since this is a redacted and simplified code snippet taken out from a much larger system. The question is - Is this a known behavior, and what might cause this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to work around this by simply using a div instead of a mat-form-field and CSS to emulate the mat-label functionality.
This is not a true answer to the question, but as you can provide all form group parameters to the div as well, it solves MY problem.